# Connection refused from external server

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

Here is my bitcoin.conf

```
server=1
rpcuser=root
rpcpassword=passwordhere
rpcconnect=75.74.28.1.2 (last 2 digits randomized for security).
rpcport=8332
rpcallowip=107.180.44.217
```

So whats the issue? When I run it via localhost it is able to connect. Externally it isn't. Ports are forwarded and are open.

Comment: Just checking: your rpcconnect ip address has 5 numbers...

Comment: yeah thats normal lol. just randomized it

Comment: Don't open the RPC server to the public internet. Use VPN or a reverse proxy: check https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.12.0.md#rpc-ssl-support-dropped

Answer (score 1):

Without indication if your `bitcoin.conf` belongs to the client or server, I leave you some guidance on what to check:

- Make sure your **server** `bitcoin.conf` has the following line:

  `rpcallowip=your.client.ip.address`
- Both **server and client** `bitcoin.conf` should contain the same `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` lines

  `rpcuser=foo`
  `rpcpassword=bar`
- Make sure your **client** `bitcoin.conf` has the following line:

  `rpcconnect=your.server.ip.address`